# Spring AOP, aspect imported from dependency not executed

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm trying to define aspects within a library module and "use" them on a SpringBoot service in another module. The following is the project structure.
[image]
I've implemented two single aspects, one inside the library module and the other within the service module

```
package it.cattanisimone.java.mvn.aspectj.controller;

public aspect LocalAspect {

    public pointcut traced(): execution(* *.*(..));

    before() : traced() {
        System.out.println("local");
    }

}


package it.cattanisimone.java.mvn.aspectjlibrary;

public aspect ImportedAspect {

    public pointcut traced(): execution(* *.*(..));

    before() : traced() {
        System.out.println("imported");
    }

}
```

The following is the library POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>java-mvn</artifactId>
        <groupId>it.cattanisimone</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.cattanisimone</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-mvn-aspectj-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And the service one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>java-mvn</artifactId>
        <groupId>it.cattanisimone</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.cattanisimone</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-mvn-aspectj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.cattanisimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-mvn-aspectj-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <mainClass>it.cattanisimone.java.mvn.aspectj.AspectServer</mainClass>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>it.cattanisimone.java.mvn.aspectj.AspectServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-io</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Running the service and calling the simple API provided by the controller, just the LocalAspect is applied

```
2018-03-27 23:46:23,014 INFO  [main]  - [] - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-03-27 23:46:23,022 INFO  [main]  - [] - Started AspectServer in 4.05 seconds (JVM running for 5.34)
2018-03-27 23:47:04,567 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1]  - [] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-27 23:47:04,568 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1]  - [] - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-03-27 23:47:04,585 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1]  - [] - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 17 ms
local
```

I’ve tried annotation based syntax, too. Same result

Comment: I am amazed hat any aspect should run because they are in native AspectJ syntax but not compiled with the AspectJ compiler. Am I missing something? Where is your AspectJ Maven plugin? And did you really run the application from your executable JAR or just from IDEA?

Comment: Spring AOP provides aspect waving without requiring AspectJ compilation. It obviously has some restrictions, but I’ve not found documentation about multi-module limitations

Comment: No AspectJ compiler present in the build, so don't expect this to work.  That is the answer to your problem. Add the AspectJ compiler to your build and specify your library module as an aspect library.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete, please read the previous comment, the LocalAspect works correctly

Comment: It's impossible to tell exactly why you have a partial success with that, might be because of the project being imported in IntelliJ and set up as an AspectJ project, but a command line `mvn clean verify` would never work with just the POMs you listed. Native AspectJ syntax **requires** the AspectJ compiler. Annotation based aspects might work with load-time weaving as well, with some limitations.

Comment: Oh, and you obviously have AspectJ support in IntelliJ since the aspect classes are marked differently from Java classes with an icon representing an A for aspect. So there is the answer to why you have partial success with your aspects. Fix your build by including the `aspectj-maven-plugin` according to the plugin documentation.